# Sonata Admin Panel Input Field

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Is there a way to add an input field to the default sonata admin panel in symfony 2?

Has anyone done this before? I can't seem to find any documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to add?

Comment: I want to add an input field box instead of the default: "add new" and "list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Symfony you can override any twig template. This is the file you are looking for:

- vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/Block/block_admin_list.html.twig

1) Copy above file into your Resources under appropriate folder.

2) Edit config.yml:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
            list_block: AppBundle:Sonata:block_admin_list.html.twig
```

Clear cache, and you are set.

You could also create your own blocks for Dashboard: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/dashboard.html